# Monit action to restart all services

Tags: monit

I have configured monit to check for my services, and I'm checking if one of the services still sane. If this service is not working as it should I would want monit to restart ALL the services I'm currently monitoring (as they sort of depend on each other).

Currently I've put all my services in one group, so I could write

```
if failed MY_TEST exec "/usr/sbin/monit -g MY_GROUP restart"
```

I wanted to do Something like:

```
if failed MY_TEST restart group MY_GROUP
```

Is there any action that I could take to do this internally (i.e. without calling monit from monit)?

Answer (score 1):

The monit guides all say you need to call monit from monit to restart a group of services. However, you could make it execute a script someplace that restarts all the services via their normal methods.